# How the time slows down? In thought experiment of special theory of relativity in which two mirrors are used how the time gets slow for moving person?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, thought-experiment

If experiment is observed from stationery frame of reference then light travels more distance than frame of reference of mirrors so to keep speed constant time for stationery frame of reference should be increased which maybe means that same event is happening slower in stationery frame because completion of same event is taking more time when viewed from that frame because distance covered has increased. Then why we say that in moving frame time passes slowly?

Comment: This is very unclear. I suspect that your question is a duplicate, but it is so unclear that it is hard to tell. I would recommend looking for duplicates and, if your question is new, explaining it as a difference from previous questions

Answer (score 2):

We don't exactly say what you just said.

We say; if you're an observer moving at some speed, your time according to you will pass normally so you won't notice your own clock running slower or faster, but when you measured time between some events (e.g. how other person's clock ticks) this time will be seen as passing slowly.

Additionally, if a stationary observer watches how your clock ticks (you are moving at some speed as in the previous example), s/he will see as if it ticks at a slower rate. This is the whole point of relativity.

Comment: I want to know actually (regardless of any human consideration) why time got slower in moving frame but why not in stationery frame because distance covered by light is more from perspective of stationary frame so time should be increased for that frame (as numerator has increased so denominator should be increased to keep speed of light constant)

Comment: What I explained above is self-sufficient. If that's not clear for you, I believe you should first learn the basics of lorentz transformation.

Comment: " _why time got slower in moving frame_ " You are asking people to explain the entire lorentz transformation to you.  It will be better if you read up on lorentz transformation and if you get stuck somewhere, then ask questions about that